# All traffic directed to single directory despite multiple virtual hosts

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtualhost, ubuntu-14.04

Everything is getting directed to the subdomain I have set up.

Something must be wrong in my virtual hosts file, because I'm pretty sure the DNS is set up correctly.

Here is the Virtual Hosts file for the main site:

```
# domain: mydomain.com
# public: /home/myusername/public/mydomain.com/

<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
  ServerName  www.mydomain.com
  ServerAlias mydomain.com

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /home/myusername/public/mydomain.com/public

  <Directory /home/myusername/public/mydomain.com/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  # Log file locations
  LogLevel debug
  ErrorLog  /home/myusername/public/mydomain.com/log/error.log
  CustomLog /home/myusername/public/mydomain.com/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is the Virtual Hosts file for the subdomain:

```
# domain: sub.mydomain.com
# public: /home/myusername/public/sub.mydomain.com/

<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
  ServerName  sub.mydomain.com

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /home/myusername/public/sub.mydomain.com/public

  <Directory /home/myusername/public/sub.mydomain.com/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /home/myusername/public/sub.mydomain.com/log/error.log
  CustomLog /home/myusername/public/sub.mydomain.com/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need this for the virtual host:
`<VirtualHost sub.mydomain.com:80>`